# The increment size of the sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm following the Learn Spring 5 etc on udemy and I'm at the part where we test our application. Everything worked fine till now, i was able to connect to the postgreSQL database and all but now I'm stuck at this test failing since 2 days.

I don't understand what is causing the Test to fail. The application run but the test doesn't. Here it is the test class:

```java
package com.ghevi.dao;

import com.ghevi.pma.ProjectManagementApplication;
import com.ghevi.pma.dao.ProjectRepository;
import com.ghevi.pma.entities.Project;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlGroup;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@ContextConfiguration(classes= ProjectManagementApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest // for temporary databases like h2
@SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = {"classpath:schema.sql", "classpath:data.sql"}),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:drop.sql")
})
public class ProjectRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository proRepo;

    @Test
    public void ifNewProjectSaved_thenSuccess(){
        Project newProject = new Project("New Test Project", "COMPLETE", "Test description");
        proRepo.save(newProject);

        assertEquals(5, proRepo.findAll().size());
    }

}
```

And this is the stack trace:

https://pastebin.com/WcjNU76p

Employee class (don't mind the comments, they are probably garbage):

```java
package com.ghevi.pma.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_seq") // AUTO for data insertion in the class projmanagapplication (the commented out part), IDENTITY let hibernate use the database id counter.
    private long employeeId;                            // The downside of IDENTITY is that if we batch a lot of employees or projects it will be much slower to update them, we use SEQUENCE now that we have schema.sql (spring does batch update)

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    // @ManyToOne many employees can be assigned to one project
    // Cascade, the query done on projects it's also done on children entities
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST}, // Standard in the industry, dont use the REMOVE (if delete project delete also children) or ALL (because include REMOVE)
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  // LAZY is industry standard it loads project into memory, EAGER load also associated entities so it slows the app, so we use LAZY and call child entities later
    //@JoinColumn(name="project_id")  // Foreign key, creates a new table on Employee database
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee",  // Merge the two table using two foreign keys
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="project_id"))

    private List<Project> projects;

    public Employee(){

    }

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    /* Replaced with List<Project>
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }
    */

    public long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Also this is the `schema.sql` where i reference those sequences, since this file is run by the test, i have just noticed that IntelliJ mark some errors in this file. For example it mark red some spaces and the T of TABLE saying:

```
expected one of the following: EDITIONING FORCE FUNCTION NO OR PACKAGE PROCEDURE SEQUENCE TRIGGER TYPE VIEW identifier
```

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS employee_seq;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( <-- here there is an error " expected: "

employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('employee_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

);

CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS project_seq;

CREATE (the error i described is here -->) TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (

project_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
stage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL

);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project_employee ( <--Here again an error "expected:"

project_id BIGINT REFERENCES project, 
employee_id BIGINT REFERENCES employee

);
```

Comment: Add stacktrace as text not as link

Comment: Read the error message: 
*The increment size of the [employee_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1].

Comment: I cannot add the stack trace because it has too many characters :/ And also the guy in the tutorial has also that warning when launching the test but it doesnt fail his test.

Comment: @Ghevi Please attach the Employee class

Comment: Also, change the title to this error message at the end of the stack: "The increment size of the [employee_seq] sequence is set to [50] in the entity mapping while the associated database sequence increment size is [1]."

Comment: i have done some edits hope it s more clear now my brain is melting smh

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You never tell it to about the sequence, just what the generator is called

Try

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_generator", sequenceName = "employee_seq", allocationSize = 1)
```

Comment: This resolved the error but now i have another one : 

GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table project (project_id bigint not null, description varchar(255), name varchar(255), stage varchar(255), primary key (project_id))" via JDBC Statement

Comment: @Ghevi I'd need to see the project class

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. Adding the below annotation resolved it. `@SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_seq", allocationSize = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

By default `allocationSize` parameter in SequenceGenerator is set to be 50. This problem arises when your sequence increment mismatches. You can either change the sequence increment value or assign allocationSize size as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, there is something wrong with the generator definition in the employee entity.
The "generator" must be the "name" of the SequenceGenerator, not the name of other things such as the sequence. Maybe Because you gave the name of the sequence, and did not have a generator with that name it used the default preallocation which is 50.

Also, the strategy should be SEQUENCE, but isn't required if you define the generator, it is only relevant when you don't define the generator.

Comment: i attached the class Employee where the strategy is indeed SEQUENCE. I'm a bit lost right now where do you define SequenceGenerator? i remember having named employee_seq and project_seq something someone, as the same as it is in these two entities

EDIT: yea i remember i named them in the schema.sql such as: 

employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('employee_seq') PRIMARY KEY